# Getting compile time errors after installing Box.V2 NuGet package

Tags: c#-4.0, box-api

I have installed lates Box.V2 v1.1.4 NuGet package into my C# Class library project that has framework 4.0. After installing project I wrote below piece of code:

```
var boxConfig = new BoxConfig(clientId, clientSecret, RedirectUrl);
var boxClient = new BoxClient(boxConfig, null);
var oAuthSession = boxClient.Auth.AuthenticateAsync(authorizationCode).Result;
```

I have also referred appropriate Box namespaces in my class file. After compilation I get below error:

"The type or namespace name 'Box' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Could you please help me to figure out the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

I just created a new project with your provided code and referenced the package from nuget. I am not getting any compilation errors. Have you tried this with a fresh project to confirm the behavior?

if you expand the References node in your project are there any yellow exclamation points?

Comment: Yes, I created a fresh project. The references did not have any missing assemblies (like yellow exclamation points)

Visual studio throws below warning after compilation:
The primary reference "System.Net.Http.Extensions" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Net.Http, Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0".

I installed latest version of Microsoft.Net.Http and the errors were gone.

Comment: Those warnings (as well as warnings in general) should not have prevented a successful compilation. Were you able to resolve your original issue as these appear to be different messages?